# How to get all TextBox values from Repeater that contains UserControls?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, repeater

I have one `TextBox` inside a `UserControl`, and this `UserControl` is repeating inside `Repeater`. 
But, when user fills `TextBox` with values and after that I can't get values from `TextBox`s.

default.aspx:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //filling repeater with dataset
    Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
}
```

On `button1` click I'm trying to fill `List<string>` with values from `textbox.text`s

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> sss = new List<string>();
    foreach (Control i in Repeater1.Controls)
    {
        foreach (Control item in i.Controls)
        {
            if (item is WebUserControl1)
                sss.Add(((WebUserControl1)item).getString);
        }
     }
}
```

And `UserControl` code:

```
public string getString
 {
     get
     { return TextBox1.Text; }
 }

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should loop on all repeater's items and use `FindControl` to find your user control then call the `getString` method on such found instances, **pseudo-code** (not tested):

```
foreach(var rptItem in Repeater1.Items)
{
  WebUserControl1 itemUserControl = ((WebUserControl1)rptItem .FindControl("WebUserControl1"))

  if(itemUserControl  != null)
  {
    var itemText = itemUserControl.getString();
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for not looping though all the controls in the `RepeaterItem`s unnecessarily =)

Comment: I have a similar problem accessing a textbox inside a usercontrol which in turn is inside a repeater. How do I reference the textbox from the user control itself? I can reference labels and change their text but somehow I cannot read from textboxes.